# Why does IntelliJ IDEA not recognise a Play 2 application during import?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to follow the ['Introduction to Play Framework'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLrmnjPQsZc) video, and the following happens:

[image]

The SBT is however installed:

[image]

Downloaded the latest edition from JetBrains plugins and installed manually from disk - the in-app browser didn't seem to find it. Any thoughts ?

Comment: What's inside `project/build.properties`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/4vbg8Ny

Comment: Any ideas what might be wrong ?

Comment: Change `sbt.version` to `0.13.6` and start over. The real question is why you had the version in the first place?!

Comment: Changed the file, the following error shows now: http://imgur.com/NIYDHih,cHbQyb3#1 (click on first image for rest of log)

Comment: Did you really follow the recording? It appears that the configuration is soooo OLD. See my answer...soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to "misconfiguration" of your project, i.e. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support sbt projects with sbt 0.12.4 and older.

You should change `project/build.properties` to:

```
sbt.version=0.13.6
```

You should also change `project/plugins.sbt` to:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")
```

I strongly advise to run `activator new playApp play-scala` to have a fresh Play application without having to change the other files if there are any more to update.

Make sure you're using [the latest version of Typesafe Activator](http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted) which should be 1.2.10. Execute `activator` and it should check whether or not an update's required.

Comment: Did what you said, got the following error "unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.3.4: not found". Did 'activator new playApp play-scala' in the command line, tried importing the project, got the same error again. Update: i managed to make it do an update; will report back if it works after. Update 2: doesn't work.

Comment: If you got the issue `play#sbt-plugin;2.3.4` it appears that it's different from what I suggested `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")` - note the organization `play` vs `com.typesafe.play`.

Comment: Can you do `activator` itself on the command line? Can you publish the project on github to take a look? Did you install activator yourself? Are you using the latest version?